# How to generate a Random number using Decimal value in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

I have a vb6 code which generate the random number. The Query is Like this:

> "xyz= Format(10000 * Rnd(-Rnd(-Val(valueData / 10000))), "000000")

I want to convert in to C# code. Currently i am using Dotnet 3.5. "valueData"  is  a return value and it is a string. In vb6 it is working fine. but in C# when i converting to integer it is not returning any decimal value. But when i change it like bellow i am getting the decimal value but I am not able to pass it to random number function. because it is accepting only integer.

> sss= Convert.ToDecimal(valueData ) / 1000000;

I meed to convert the above code in to C#. any help will be usefull for me."

Answer (score 1):

Blurgh!  Forget that VB6 code altogether.  In .NET, create a `Random` object and call the appropriate method.  The `NextDouble` method will return a `Double` value `d` where 0 <= `d` < 1.  You can then do whatever scaling or translation or rounding you need to massage that into the desired range.  **DO NOT** at any point convert the number to a `String` to get what you want.  That's an example of why VB6 gets looked down on by those who use other languages.

Comment: That VB6 code I am trying to convert in to C#. So what Output i am getting in VB6 i expected the same result. if i break the code in to steps then: sss= Convert.ToDecimal(valueData ) / 1000000 will give me the decimal value. after this output how i will pass to "NextDouble" as it is not taking any arrgument.

Comment: please make sure i want to convert that VB6 line of code to C#  so that i can get the exact output as vb6